Projection measure and an integral formula for Lipschitz functions
Let $n\geq m\geq 0$ be integers and put $k=n-m$. Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be Borel measurable, we define the projection measure of $A$ as
$$\mu_k(A):=\underset{P_1, \ldots, P_r}{\sup_{A=A_1\sqcup\ldots\sqcup A_r}}\lambda(P_1(A_1))+\cdots+\lambda(P_r(A_r)),$$
where $A$ is written as a disjoint union of an arbitrary finite number of Borel measurable sets $A_1,\ldots, A_r$, and where $P_1,\ldots,P_r$ are linear surjections from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^k$ whose restriction to the orthogonal complement of their respective kernels are required to be isometries. Here $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^k$. Note that the projection of a Borel measurable set is always Lebesgue measurable. We extend $\mu_k$ to a complete measure (so that any subset of a $\mu_k$-negligible set is again $\mu_k$-measurable).
Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, and let
$$T:U\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$$
be locally Lipschitz continuous. We will use the fact that $T$ is almost everywhere differentiable. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^m\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ be Lebesgue measurable.
Does the following formula always hold?
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)g(T(x))|\det(DT(x)|_{\ker^\bot})|d\lambda(x)\overset{?}{=}\int_{\mathbb{R}^m}g(y)\Big(\int_{T^{-1}(\{y\})}f(x)d\mu_k(x)\Big)d\lambda(y)$$
Here $|\det(DT(x)|_{\ker^\bot})|$ is an abusive notation which we define to be zero if $DT:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is not surjective, and if it is surjective we take a linear isometry $\iota$ from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose image is the orthoganal complement of the kernel of $DT(x)$, and define
$$|det(DT(x)|_{\ker^\bot})|:=|\det(DT(x)\circ\iota)|.$$
There may be values of $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$ for which the restriction of $f$ to the set $T^{-1}(\{y\})$ is not $\mu_k$-measurable, but this isn't a problem as long as the set of such bad $y$ has Lebesgue measure zero, which I hope to always hold.
If this were to fail, is there another measure, like Hausdorff measure, that could be used instead?
Note that if $m=n$ and $k=0$, the formula becomes
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)g(T(x))|\det(DT(x))|d\lambda(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}g(y)\sum_{x\in T^{-1}(\{y\})} f(x)d\lambda(y).$$
If $m=0$ and $n=k$, then $\mu_k$ becomes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and the formula becomes trivial.
